# Can't connect PowerBi to Azure Data Explorer, getting "Authorization has been denied for this request"

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-explorer, azureportal

I created an Azure Data Explorer cluster, I created a Data Connection to an Event Hub.
I can get events from Kusto queries.

Now I want to connect it to PowerBi.

I did the following:

[image: Data Explorer Connector]

[image: Data Explorer Connector]

When I click **connect**, I'm getting the following message:

[image: Error Message]

I'm the owner of the resource Data Explorer, and I'm logging in to PowerBi using the same Azure Portal credentials.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: Could you please let us know if you have specified the database name in the dialog box when you are trying to login powerBI

Comment: I've not specified the database name, as it says it's optional

Comment: Can you specified the database name and try the same

Comment: Yes, I did that also but still getting the  same error message

Answer (score 0):

Is "my cluster" the "[start for free](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/start-for-free-web-ui)" Kusto cluster? If so you should use the URL of the cluster that is located in the top right of the "my cluster" page, in the "cluster details" section for the cluster address

Comment: The cluster is not the "start for free" cluster. I'm using the URI property in the "Overview" section which is in the form "https://<ClusterName>.<Region>.kusto.windows.net".